# jQuery ticker plugin bug in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, ticker

Here at www.islyamov.site90.net I use Alex Fish's Ticker plugin (http://alexfish.heroku.com/posts/21) to animate list items. List is styled properly with CSS, and you can see red, yellow and blue bubbles replacing one another.

**The problem is, when Chrome loads the page first time, ticker stops functioning on yellow bubble, however when you refresh the page, it works properly and displays all three list items with text. 
So, what is the problem and how to fix it?**

Here is the Plugin code http://plugins.jquery.com/files/ticker.js_1.txt
Here is the script within document

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ticker').list_ticker({
                speed:2000,
                effect:'fade'
        })              
})
```

Comment: experienced no problem in chrome 13

Comment: I have Chrome 13, still I face the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing run_once:false, looks like it's causing the bug in chrome, using this worked for me:

https://gist.github.com/1143861

Answer (score 0):

To rotate list items you can also use another jQuery plugin the [jQuery Web Ticker](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/) it works with all browsers. This enables you extended use especially if you have wordpress or another CMS which already bundles jQuery making your download footprint much smaller then alternatives.